# Failed to execute setblock as arrow

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried to write this command but it printed an error: `Failed to execute 'setblock' as arrow`.

This is the command I'm using:

```
/execute @e[type=minecraft:arrow] -10 8 18 detect ~ ~ ~ gold_block 0 setblock 0 5 0 gold_block 0
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your commands, post the actual commands.  It makes it a lot easier for us to troubleshoot your issue if it's just the text, and the images gain you nothing.

Comment: What version are you in? This is 1.13 incompatible synax.

Comment: Oh, I know see the problem. You are trying to execute an arrow if it detects a block at its position, but that is impossible unless the arrow is inside the block, which does not happen if you shoot it at the block.

Answer (score -1):

The basic command format is either

`/execute [entity or player] x y z detect x y z [type of block]`

or

`/execute [entity or player] x y z [command]`.

You cannot use `detect` and `setblock` together, in your case.

An alternative can be:

`/execute @e[type=minecraft:arrow] -10 8 18 detect ~ ~ ~ gold_block 0` (repeating command block)

then in another cmd block (conditional chain command block),

`/execute @e[type=minecraft:arrow] ~ ~ ~ setblock 0 5 0 gold_block 0`.

This only works if there is only one existing arrow at a time.

Comment: "detect" is an addendum to the syntax for `/execute` and does work with another command.

Comment: well now you can... i don't think you could have earlier when this post ewas created